# Allegations of hat-fishing, and a humble apology

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Today I asked 2 questions about Skyrim, a game I've never played.  I also answered one question through some crafty internet research (tm).

[One of my questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42214/what-is-fus-ro-dah) has been accused of being *blatant hat fishing*, but only sarcastically.  However, the sarcastic comment got 4 upvotes, and the question itself has 4 downvotes and 2 close votes.  Someone who saw the question in the chat feed also protested it.

It is safe to say that I am venturing outside my comfort zone in terms of game questions - I have ignored several tags on this site previously that are games that are seriously popular, but I don't play.  However, for the purposes of this Hat competition I've been trying to find ways to make a small contribution to questions and answers with those tags.

I honestly have spent 0 hours playing Skyrim, and know very little about the game mechanics and the plot/story/setting, aside from what I know from playing both Morrowind and Oblivion.  The question is easy - this part of the game is a meme, and I'm sure if I plugged "fus ro dah" into google I could probably figure it out in a few clicks.  Then again, I don't know that the simplicity of answering a question is a barrier to posting it.  I felt like perhaps it being so popular, having a question on it would not be off-topic.

However, I feel like, although this was not my intent, some among us feel I toed or crossed a line that I should not have crossed.  If you are one of those people who felt this way, I apologize.  I'd hate to cause issues over something so very silly as a *hat* that means effectively nothing and will disappear in a few weeks regardless of what happens.  Please forgive my collectible OCD, and any offense I may have caused by stepping outside my comfort zone.

...or perhaps it was just a bad question, in which case I'll commit to do better next time.

If the question is truly bad or off topic, I have no issues with it being closed or deleted completely.  Regardless, I furthermore commit to answering or asking at least one additional question about Skyrim so that if anyone feels my "hat" is "unjust," I will have atoned.

I hope that this apology is accepted in the sincere manner in which it is offered.

Comment: FWIW, it didn't seem like hat fishing to me, but as a fellow non-Skyrim player I'm slightly mad that you beat me to asking that. I'd been kind of wondering the same thing. :P

Comment: @AnnaLear seems like you wanted to ask the question, but then took an arrow to the knee ;)

Comment: I'm sorry I opened this can of worms. And here I thought I was just making a joke. :/

Comment: For what it's worth, your question was extraordinarily enlightening to Gnomeslice, who had no idea what Fus Ro Dah was until your question was linked in chat.

Comment: That wasn't the only allegation of fishing either, I [posted one on The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2746153#2746153), too.  Particularly since the original subject was "If my car broke down, would I need to Fus Ro Dah it to a mechanic?"

Comment: @powerlord, Yeah, I knew it had something to do with *pushing* from context, so I thought that might be a fun title.  I think Raven changed it, I added it as a postscript to the question since he'd referenced it in his answer.  I mentioned your opposition but didn't use your name.

Comment: Honestly, I feel like your Minecraft question was more hat-fishing than this one.

Comment: Apologies if that was a problem.  I think I was at 3 for minecraft before I posted that - I was going to ask that in chat, but I figured I could probably help someone else get a hat if I posted it as a question.  This whole thing has turned out to be waaaay more drama than I was expecting.  I'll try to make up for it.

Answer (score 10):

Just my opinion, but somebody should say it so we can vote it up or down and make a collective decision :)

I think it's a perfectly good question.  You're right that it's becoming a meme, and not everyone knows what it means.  As far as I'm concerned, it passes the sniff-test of "Would a real gamer ask this?", and "Does it have a real, definitive answer?".  There *are* already several answers out there ([Know your meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fus-ro-dah) and [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110414161302AAeEQIm) come up first for me) but in my opinion our answer is more direct than Know your meme and more informative than Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: Raven Dreamer: Officially more informative than *Yahoo! Answers* \o/

Comment: @RavenDreamer I'd add it to your resume.

Comment: I would like to add that I just used the question for reference, (just to find out the spelling, but still) and came to Gaming.SE cause I knew I'd get the right answer. Seems on topic and useful to me.

Comment: I agree, the question was valid enough in my mind.  I cast the final reopen vote, so the question is back in its former glory.

Answer (score 6):

Even if the question was hat-fishing *which I'm not saying it was*, I'm not sure that I could, in good conscience, blame a gamer, on a gaming website, for treating an event about earning hats as if it was a game.

Comment: See also: ["Is Hat Dash a game?"](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3564/is-hat-dash-a-game)