# Arqade year in review - your input requested!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

> The [blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/10/happy-second-anniversary-arqade/?cb=1) is up!  Thanks for your help.

On October 6th, 2010, gaming.stackexchange.com graduated from beta status!  In celebration of the 2 year anniversary of this date, I'm working on a "year in review" blog post.

I'm going to hit all the highlights - the major events, skyrim, arqade, etc.  However, I know I don't know all the cool stuff that went on this past year, (I haven't been paying attention 24/7 in chat, comments, minecraft, youtube, twitter, let's play, etc) and so I'd like *your* input.

**What happened this year that was awesome or silly or fun that deserves recognition?**

Here's some quick guidelines:

- This is going to be "year in review" style, so feel free to make up awards (Wipqozn's award for most awesome turtle pic, etc) or just give an anecdote, or whatever in between.
- Let's keep it positive - so let's not honor bad behavior or trolling, etc.  Also, let's try not to be mean to other people unless they're OK with being the butt of the joke :P
- Try to keep it relatively short, a paragraph or so.  I'd like to include a bunch of different things from different sources.  However, if you'd like to write a longer article for the blog, we can probably work something out!
- I'll also accept art, or art help.  I suck at art.  Seriously, you don't want me to art you again.

I'll be publishing the article on October 6th (assuming no wrinkles surface) so you have until then to submit your anecdote/thought/award/whatever.  I'll include as many as I can, and I'll try to give preferential treatment to highly upvoted submissions.

Comment: Isn't it positive that we now have our first recurring troll, traveling backwards in times with its robotic implants?

Comment: Also do any blog posts on Arqade involve time traveling robots?

Comment: Do you want to have stuff that happened almost entirely in chat? I'm thinking of back in February, when several of us got pony avatars and went a little crazy posting ponies in chat.

Comment: @badp he wasn't pro much.  That's the standard by which we judge our trolls around here.

Comment: @murgatroid99, stuff that happened almost entirely in chat (or on another arqade community spot) is well within what I'm looking for.

Comment: [Everyone loves Magic cards](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3775/so-i-heard-you-like-magic-cards)

Comment: Of course you post this when I don't have the time to compose a proper [tag:murder] ballad. That said, we need a [tag:murder] ballad to tell the tale of the murder of [tag:murder] at the hands of The Coward Grace Note.

Comment: I, for one, highly support the idea of a Wipqozn Award for most awesome turtle pic.

Comment: Are we only going for events since January 1, or are we going until last Octoberish?

Comment: @DaveMcClelland, I'm including stuff that happened since the last anniversary, so anything from Oct. 6th 2011 -> Oct 6th 2012 is fair game.

Comment: @desaivv, hah, you caught me :)  I honestly didn't think anyone would notice.  I also felt weird writing a blog post about *how awesome I am.*  Therefore, I left myself out, as much as possible.

Comment: @desaivv, d'aww, thanks :)  Hope you enjoyed the blog post and thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 14):

I'm quite surprised everyone's missed a rather big one: [we changed our name!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/introducing-arqade)

Other things that haven't been mentioned:

- [We hosted (and continue to host) some community servers](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/se-are-funding-a-server-for-community-building)
- [We made some industry friends](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4443/nuclear-dawn-giveaway)
- [We got our name out there](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/the-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-by-gaming-stackexchange-league-of-legends-t)
- [We murdered](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/whither-murder) [murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder)
- [And](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/spoiler-alert-spoiler-dies) [spoiler](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler)
- [We cleaned ourself up](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012)

Comment: +1, These are the most important milestones we reached in the past year, really.

Comment: @GnomeSlice That's a very subjective comment.

Comment: +1 for a serious post that actually addresses some of our main achievements!

Answer (score 10):

I have a few suggestions, which I'll list in no particular order.

- Lazers.
- Discuss some of the [memes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/the-memes-of-arqade-and-its-chat) that have come and gone over the years. Discussing all of them would take up too much space, but touching on some of the major ones would  be a good idea.
- Lazers.
- The events and promotions that have happened over the past year, and the growth of the site in general (including the renaming).
- Lazers.
- Assuming someone has the skill and tools to make one, and is also willing to take the time (*cough* @RonanForman *cough*), a short montage video of some of the awesome things that have happened over the course of Arqade's lifetime would be a really nice way to round off the blog post.
- Lazers.

Comment: +1 for lazers!!

Comment: I think you forgot Lazers.

Answer (score 8):

[identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) questions were banned from the site. Depending on your point of view, there was either much rejoicing, or it was if millions of voices suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced.

Or maybe there was much rejoicing *because* a million voices were suddenly silenced.

Comment: I was going to go grab a link for this, then remembered that there were approximately 1000 discussions on the subject

Comment: It was fun for me to mass delete them... oh, good times

Answer (score 7):

I suppose it's worth mentioning the fantastic support from all the people here at Arqade during this year's [Mario Marathon](http://www.mariomarathon.com/). We started off at #1 before the event even started.

We held the number one spot for the first day (or two) of the event, and we still stayed strong at the end, finishing at number five in the Top Contributors.

Also, as Wipqozn stated, we were still in the lead for average donations per user!

Additionally, we've made extremely good progress on tag clean-up!

And let's not forget: spugly pls

Comment: It's worth noting that we still come in first for highest average donation per user.

Answer (score 4):

In mid January, Tristan (now known as [Fluttershy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/14775/fluttershy)) [changed his gravatar to a picture of Fluttershy](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/first-pony-avatar-conversation) and [Wipqozn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8350/wipqozn) revealed that he, too, was a brony. Within a few days, he and I ([murgatroid99](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1787/murgatroid99)) followed suit with pony avatars (Applejack and Twilight Sparkle, respectively). [Ashley Nunn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/11502/ashley-nunn) eventually started watching and joined us with a Rainbow Dash avatar, and later a Derpy Hooves avatar. In our excitement we flooded chat with pony pictures several times (examples [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/pony-posts-example-2) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/pony-posts-example-1)), to the chagrin of others who did not share our enthusiasm for the show. There was a bit of drama over posting pony pictures in the chat, and especially one-boxing them and posting a lot at once, but it eventually blew over. Now a couple of us still have My Little Pony related avatars, and we link to MLP content infrequently enough that people rarely express annoyance about it, though apparently some are just annoyed and silent.

Comment: Every time my 3 year old sees my Dragonvale park she says "I want to go to @Fluttershy 's park." Heh...

Comment: We rarely express annoyance because all it would do is keep you people on the subject longer. But, for the sake of a fact check: this is still insufferable and I hate you all.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz OK. What I said is consistent with your comment. This isn't really the time or place for an argument about this, so I won't.

Comment: Count me in for "infrequent enough that I don't mind it anymore." :)

Comment: Yep. Started as RD, then was Derpy for a while.

Comment: What is a Brony? (I know it, but isn't the idea behind SE that we make it easy to search in google? ;) ).

Comment: I'm sorry, what? I wrote this post to describe an event in the community, not describe a cultural phenomenon. And that argument really only applies to our actual Q&A topic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are people downvoting because of something about the story or for some other reason?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Wild Guess: It has something to do with the number of upvotes my comment received.

Answer (score 4):

### Shameless Self-Promotion

[I wrote poetry](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/78630/5398).

### Other Cool Stuff I Remember

- There was that time when [there were hats](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3564/5398) for a while (Remember?  That was when people [got mad at you.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3488/5398)) (actually, you know what?  I'm [still mad at you](http://stackexchange.com/users/1026765/agent86?tab=reputation))  :]
- The various game grants.
- The [Steam Game Trading Thread](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3536/5398).  I think this was one of the cooler things we've done as a community.

Answer (score 1):

We quickly ravaged the Kingdoms of Amalur followed shortly after by a huge give away with the Mass Effect 3 launch.  The subsequent launch of Diablo 3 meant that the front page of the site was swamped for months!! :)

Comment: Not to mention Skyrim vs. MW3 about a year ago.

Comment: Skyrim vs. MW3 was a year ago? Crikey.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually got it yet, but there was a giveaway of Arqade swag for everyone in the first 5 pages for rep; iirc for the first time ever.

The Diablo III event was the first time that all qualifying participants got a prize, and also the first time that this prize (t-shirt) had the new name & logo on it.

Comment: This is actually the second time Top User swag was sent out, [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/gaming-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) was the first, though the first was for the top 2 pages and this was for the top 5.